# Obtaining the split value after java string split

Tags: java, split

I have a string that is dynamially generated.

I need to split the string based on the Relational Operator.

For this I can use the split function.

Now I would also like to know that out of the regex mentioned above, based on which Relational Operator was the string actually splitted.

An example,
On input

```
String sb = "FEES > 200";
```

applying

```
List<String> ls =  sb.split(">|>=|<|<=|<>|=");
System.out.println("Splitted Strings: "+s);
```

will give me the result,

```
Splitted strings: [FEES ,  200 ]
```

But expecting result:

```
Splitted strings: [FEES ,  200 ]
Splitted Relational Operator: >
```

Comment: You could split the `String` a second time, and that time split it by a space. Then iterate and find the operator, maybe using a `switch` statement with all possible operator `String`s.

Comment: You can use regex with Pattern.matches(), to capture the split operator into group.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use 3 capturing groups with an alternation for the second group:

`(.*?)(>=|<=|<>|>|<)(.*)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ki4weh/1)

**Explanation**

- `(.*?)` Match any character zero or more times non greedy
- `(>=|<=|<>|>|<)` Match either `>=` or `<=` or `<>` or `>` or `<`
- `(.*)` Match any character zero or more times

For example:

```
String regex = "(.*?)(>=|<=|<>|>|<)(.*)";
String string = "FEES >= 200";            
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Splitted Relational Operator: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Group 1: " + matcher.group(1) + " group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

[Demo java](http://rextester.com/TVUOA36851)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use regex, which is more flexible in your case.

```
String sb = "FEES > 200";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(>=|<=|<>|=|>|<)(.*)");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(sb);
if (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println("Groups: " + mat.group(1) + ", " + mat.group(3));
    System.out.println("Operator: " + mat.group(2));
}
```

Comment: `(.*?)(>=|<=|<>|>|<)(.*)` use this regex instead.

Comment: @SumeshTG you are right, we need to start with the longest ones, updated

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pattern` to do this.

```
String sb = "FEES > 200";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(>|>=|<|<=|<>|=)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Grouped params: " + matcher.group(1) + "," + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("Split operator: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

**Note that :**

- `matcher.group(0)` --> All string
- `matcher.group(1)` --> first part of matching
- `matcher.group(2)` --> split operator
- `matcher.group(3)` --> second part of matching

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pattern matcher` to match the delimeters. Example shown below -

```
public static int indexOf(Pattern pattern, String s) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sb = "FEES > 200";
    String[] s =  sb.split(">|>=|<|<=|<>|=");
    System.out.println("Splitted Strings: "+ s);

    int index = indexOf(Pattern.compile(">|>=|<|<=|<>|="), sb);
    System.out.println("del "+ sb.charAt(index));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) if you want exclude number from your string:

> replaceAll("\d", ""); - this replace all number on white space

To delete unnecessary words you need to give more information. Because there are different ways of doing things.