# Splitting strings when argument exists in different forms in the input

Tags: java, regex, parsing

So I'm new to Java and would like some help here. I have a string like so,

```
`( ( t1.INDEX BETWEEN  100 and 200 ) OR ( t1.INDEX BETWEEN  'AAA' and 'BBB' ) AND ( t1.INDEX IN('AAA','BBB') ) AND ( t1.INDEX = 'AAA' OR t1.INDEX = 'BBB' ) OR ( t1.INDEX=123 ) )`
```

I would like to split this into sub expressions like so,

```
`Expression = ( t1.INDEX BETWEEN  100 and 200 )
Operator = OR
Expression = ( t1.INDEX BETWEEN  'AAA' and 'BBB' )
Operator = AND
Expression = ( t1.INDEX IN('AAA','BBB') )
Operator = AND
Expression = ( t1.INDEX = 'AAA' OR t1.INDEX = 'BBB' )
Operator = OR
Expression = ( t1.INDEX=123 )`
```

What would be the best way to do this in java? I went through [Multi-level String split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928018/multi-level-string-split) but its wont handle parantheses.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be using a parser, like [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) or [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/).

You could also split it with regex using brackets as expression separators, but that's some buggy and troublesome solution, especially if your grammar is much more complex than you have shown.