# Matching specific operator using regex

Tags: java, regex

So this is a followup of [Splitting strings when argument exists in different forms in the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255391/splitting-strings-when-argument-exists-in-different-forms-in-the-input)

I have a string like

```
INDEX IN('AAA','BBB')
```

I would like to split it like so,

```
INDEX, IN, ('AAA','BBB')
```

This is the regular expression I'm using,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(>=|<=|<>|>|<|BETWEEN|IN|=)(.*)");
```

This is the result I'm getting,

```
IN , DEX IN'AAA','BBB'
```

Can someone help me with my regular expression a bit?

Comment: Note that regular expressions aren't a good fit for irregular problems like yours (which seems to be code). As an example what would happen if instead of `'AAA'` you'd have `'INDEX BETWEEN AAA'`? (That's a construed example but unless you _know_ what those strings can contain you'll always have to assume it could happen).

Comment: Use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)([><]=|<>|[><=]|\\b(?:BETWEEN|IN)\\b)(.*)");`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jKlRAI/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `.*?` matches as few chars as possible up to the first occurrence of the subsequent patterns and the next subpattern can match `IN` (and `BETWEEN`) as a part of a word.

You can't simply add word boundaries around Group 2 since non-word chars with word boundaries around them will not match in non-word context.

You may fix the regex using

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)([><]=|<>|[><=]|\\b(?:BETWEEN|IN)\\b)(.*)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jKlRAI/1).

**Details**

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `([><]=|<>|[><=]|\\b(?:BETWEEN|IN)\\b)` - `>` or `<` and then `=`, or `<>`, or `<`, `>`, `=`, or `BETWEEN` or `IN` as whole words
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the post you have linked [Splitting strings when argument exists in different forms in the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255391/splitting-strings-when-argument-exists-in-different-forms-in-the-input), the best approach would be using a Domain Specific Language (DSL), like ANTLR or JavaCC.

As example, a very simple ANTLR4 Grammar like the following:

```
grammar simpleTest
start : 'INDEX' 'IN' '(' '\'' .*? '\'' ',' '\'' .*? '\''  ')';
```

Would produce, when parsed your input, one Tree with the following TreeNodes:

```
TreeChildNode[0]  = INDEX
TreeChildNode[1]  = IN
TreeChildNode[2]  = (
TreeChildNode[3]  = '
TreeChildNode[4]  = AAA // AAA could any sequence of char of any length
TreeChildNode[5]  = '
TreeChildNode[6]  = ,
TreeChildNode[7]  = '
TreeChildNode[8]  = BBB // BBB could any sequence of char of any length
TreeChildNode[9]  = '
TreeChildNode[10] = )
```

So you can reorganize your input at your convenience.